# How to fade in and out a success message after page reload with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched this topic a lot and got a lot of different responses, however, none of them work for me.

I have a form that when it gets successfully submitted, reloads the page.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
if($('#input').val() == 0){
    alert("Please insert your name");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Now, on each successful submit I want a success message to slide at the top, stay there for 2 sec and then fade out.

I tried this, however, it doesn't stay after the page was reloaded.

```
else{
     $('.success_message').fadeIn(1500);   
  }
```

Is that possible in pure jQuery?

Also, I am not looking for a way to reload the page. The page gets reloaded automatically after submitting the form.

Comment: You have to print the success message with the backend language if you don't send the form via Ajax.

Comment: yes, however, that doesn't work, I can't use the success messages from the backend language

Comment: ok, however, this I have seen a lot around here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submitting the form, set a value in `localStorage` indicating that the success message should fade in:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  if ($('#input').val() == 0){
    alert("Please insert your name");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  localStorage.fadeInSuccessMessage = "1"
});
```

Then check if the value exists in `localStorage`. If yes, fade in the message and delete the value from `localStorage`:

```
if ("fadeInSuccessMessage" in localStorage) {
  $('.success_message').fadeIn(1500);
  delete localStorage.fadeInSuccessMessage;
}
```